# Паттерн Decoratot в существующей иерархии классов

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть некая иерархия игровых ресурсов. На вершине иерархии класс Resource. У него есть некие данные которыми обладают все подклассы этого класса. И само собой некие методы. Ниже стоят классы Bag, Transport, Food, Clothes и т д. У каждого из этих классов есть свои дополнительные данные и методы. Я хочу применить паттерн декоратор к этой иерархии. Один из декораторов будет самоапдейтить объект при внесении в него изменений (объекты хранятся в бд), Логирующий декоратор и т д. Проблема в том что я не знаю как применить паттерн декоратор к существующей иерархии классов. Все примеры декораторов которые я видел, не применялись к некой иерархии классов. Там просто было пару классов с одинаковым набором методов и данных. И получается что требовалось написать одну обёртку и в нее можно было оборачивать любой из этих объектов. У меня же получается что под каждый объект надо написать свою логирующую, обновляющую и т д обёртку, так как набор методов и данных разный у каждого объекта. И что очень важно, у меня должна сохраниться иерархия классов.

Comment: декоратор только усложняет понимание вашей логики. ее будет знать только вы. а представьте, если нужно будет использовать ваши классы сторонним разработчикам

Comment: возможно стоит расширять классы с помощью наследования (базовые классы объявляют методы с логированием, логикой обновления и т.д), либо написать бины/хелперы для выполнения этих действий. Вообще Ваш вопрос получился слишком абстрактным, без конкретных классов и методов тут сложно что либо подсказать